# What is the difference in usage between 似乎 and 宛如?

Tags: difference

Both 似乎 and 宛如 are translated in the same way ("as if..."). What are some examples where using one would be more appropriate than the other?

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g. bkrs **似乎** #642（fr.rk.)
 **宛如** #15115 正像；好像：欢腾的人群宛如大海的波涛;仿佛 绚烂的晚霞, 宛如一幅锦绣

Answer (score 3, accepted):

似乎(as if; seem like) is more modern and colloquial, 宛如(just like; as if) is very classical and literary

似乎 mainly refer to metaphorical resemblance, 宛如 mainly refers to physical resemblance

Example:

**似乎**要打仗了 (**seem like** we will go to war)

**似乎**忘了自己是誰 (**seem like**/ **as if** forgotten who he is)

五座山峰一列排開，**宛如**五指，故名五指山 (the five mountain peaks stand side by side, **just like** five fingers in human hand, hence the name 'Five Fingers Mountains'

看他面目猙獰，**宛如**惡鬼猛獸 (look at his ferocious face, **just like** a demon or a beast)

*The modern/colloquial equivalent of '宛如' is '就像'*